# Add a task to copy files from my resources folder to a target

Tags: sbt, scalajs-bundler

I have a scala js project that uses the sbt-scalajs-bundler plugin. When I run the webpack command most of the necessary files are bundled to the **target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main** folder. I have placed my html resources (such as index.html, myproject.css, etc) in the **src/main/resources** folder of my project. But these are not included in my bundle. Should I add an sbt task to copy these files and if so how would I add such a task?

My build.sbt is something like the following:

```
import sbt.addCommandAlias
import scalajsbundler.sbtplugin.ScalaJSBundlerPlugin.autoImport.webpackDevServerPort

enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

val scalaJSReactVersion = "1.4.1"
val reactJSVersion = "16.8.6"

lazy val myProject = project.in(file(".")).settings(

    name := "My Project",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.6",
        "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.4",
        "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "core" % scalaJSReactVersion,
        "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "extra" % scalaJSReactVersion,
        "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalarx" % "0.4.0"
    ),

    npmDependencies in Compile ++= Seq(
        "react" -> reactJSVersion,
        "react-dom" -> reactJSVersion,
        "bootstrap" -> "4.3.1",
    ),

    scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,

    webpackDevServerPort := 3000

)

addCommandAlias("serve", ";fastOptJS::startWebpackDevServer;~fastOptJS")
addCommandAlias("devBuild", "fastOptJS::webpack")
addCommandAlias("build", "fullOptJS::webpack")
```

Comment: There might be some confusion about what scalajs-bundler does: it bundles a JavaScript application that uses the CommonJS module style into a JavaScript application executable by web browsers. It is possible to include resources like .html and .css files into the bundle (as strings) but this might not be what you are looking for. Can you elaborate on your needs? How do you want to use the HTML document from your JavaScript bundle?

Comment: My html document defines the main page for my app - containing the dom the react component gets rendered into. I also have resources such as icons and i18n json that needs to be copied over.

Comment: In that case, I guess you *don’t* want to bundle the HTML file with the JS application. You probably want to serve both the HTML file and the JS application from a web server.

Comment: Which means I can't use the webpackDevServer in my development cycle?

Comment: It should be possible by adding a “resolve alias” like this: https://github.com/shadaj/slinky/blob/f8f3a6c1ed012aed4af47132d03b193f93f2a172/docs/webpack-fastopt.config.js#L21